# Composition relation of P∘P

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

Consider the following relation P on the set B = {a, b, {a, b}}:

P = {(a, a), (a, b), (b, {a, b}), ({a, b}, a)}.

Answer questions 6 to 8 by using the given relation P.

Question 6 
Which one of the following alternatives represents the domain of P (dom(P))?

1. {a, b}
2. {{a, b}}
3. a, b, {a, b}
4. {a, b, {a, b}}

Question 7 
Which one of the following relations represents the composition relation P ○ P?

1. {(a, a),(a, b), (a, {a, b}), (b, a)}
2. {(a, a),(a, b), (a, {a, b}), (b, a), ({a, b}, a), ({a, b}, b)}
3. {(a, a),(a, b), (b, a)}
4. {(a, a),(a, b), (b, a), ({a, b}, {a, b})}

Question 8 
The relation P is not transitive. Which ordered pairs can be included in P so that P would satisfy 
transitivity?

1. (a, {a, b}) & (b, a)
2. (b, b) & ({a, b}, {a, b})
3. (b, a), (b, b), (a, {a, b}), ({a, b}, b) & ({a, b}, {a, b})
4. (b, a), (a, {a, b}) & ({a, b}, b)

Comment: For the most part, it would considerably simplify your life to let $c=\{a,b\}$ and re-write the problem with $c$ instead.

Comment: Is this a school assignment?!

Answer (score 0):

Question 6 :

> 4

domain of P is the entire set B

Question 7:

> 2

you just need to write it down and compose!

Question 8:

> 1

when $p .  p \subseteq p$ then p is transitive.